# Pandas date_range with timezone error, possible bug?

Tags: python, pandas, date

So I am trying this code:

```
observed_df_new_index = pd.date_range('1962-01-01', '2018-01-01',
                                      freq='1D', tz='Asia/Kathmandu')
```

and I get this error:

```
File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 989, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.tz_localize_to_utc
pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError: 1986-01-01 00:00:00
```

Which made me think that there is something wierd about Jan 1, 1986. So then I tried this:

```
UTC = pytz.timezone('UTC')
asia = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kathmandu')

x = datetime.datetime(1986, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=UTC)
print(x.replace(tzinfo=asia))
```

and it works fine. Is there something that I am doing wrong or does it just not like that date and particular timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is beacuse there is no `1986-01-01 00:00:00`

After `1985-12-31 11:59:59 PM`, Clocks were jumped to `1986-01-01 12:15:00 AM`, so `1986-01-01 00:00:00` just being skip. which means the clock had been set forward 15mins

Comment: Wait really? Is that because the time zone changed that day or something?

Comment: @Wade you can search for more information http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zoneinfo.tzc?s=default&tz=Asia/Katmandu