# Pandas date_range unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date-range

If I run:

```
pd.date_range('2022-01-01 15:00', '2023-02-02 00:00', freq='YS')
```

I receive:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01 15:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='AS-JAN')
```

I would expect to get 2023-01-01 15:00:00 in the return as well, i.e.

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01 15:00:00', '2023-01-01 15:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='AS-JAN')
```

Feel this is really strange. Am I missing anything or is it a bug? How may I achieve the expected behaviour?

Thanks

Edit: agree with s_pike, this behaviour looks quite counter-intuitive and I would say it's a bug.

Comment: That definitely looks like a bug. `pd.date_range('2022-01-01 15:00', '2023-02-02 16:00', freq='YS')` gives you the result you expect, but `pd.date_range('2022-01-01 15:00', '2023-02-02 14:00', freq='YS')` doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your desired output by:

```
pd.date_range('2022-01-01 15:00', '2023-01-01 15:00', freq='YS')

#DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01 15:00:00', '2023-01-01 15:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='AS-JAN')
```

If you change your date to February you must change time to greater than or equal time given in start date.

```
pd.date_range('2022-01-01 15:00', '2023-02-02 15:00', freq='YS')

#DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01 15:00:00', '2023-01-01 15:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='AS-JAN')
```

If you less time than the time specified in the start date then you will not get the result:

```
pd.date_range('2022-01-01 15:00', '2023-02-02 14:59', freq='YS')

#DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01 15:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='AS-JAN')
```

here are the links to documents:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it's a bug? Looks quite counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: @Jian... please see these links https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/46331; 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283103/bug-or-feature-generating-a-pd-date-range-from-july-15-for-monthly-frequency-pr; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978492/pandas-date-range-with-timezone-error-possible-bug

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, this might provide your expected result.

```
date_range = pd.date_range('2022-01-01 15:00', '2023-02-02 00:00', freq='AS')
date_range = date_range.union(pd.DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-01 15:00']))
```

This `pd.DatetimeIndex()` constructor will create a new "datetimeindex".